# How to get the current block in apeworx?

Tags: ape

How do I get the current block in [apeworx](https://docs.apeworx.io/ape/stable/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
ape.chain.blocks.head.number
```

You can see the [API here.](https://docs.apeworx.io/ape/stable/methoddocs/managers.html#ape.managers.chain.BlockContainer.head)